# Integer/Binary Programming - Convert nonlinear constraint to linear constraint

Tags: matrices, integer-programming, binary-programming

I have a constraint based on matrix multiplication.  It involves summation of a product.  The product multiplies two entries of a variable matrix named *order*, and an entry of a constant matrix named *guess*.

All of the variables and constants are binary.  All of the indexes have the same arbitrary range $N$.

($\forall n,m$) result$_{n,m}$ = $\sum_r \sum_s$ (order$_{n,r}$ * guess$_{r,s}$ * order$_{m,s}$)

Is it possible to turn this into ~$N^2$ linear constraints?

Answer (score 1):

You can linearize each product of binary variables by introducing a new binary variable and three linear constraints:
https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-binary-variables

That is $O(N^4)$ linear constraints.  See the references in the linked answer for formulations that use fewer constraints.